# Calling an action method that return Json is not woking when i publish my web application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have the following script on my view:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Rack_DataCenterID").change(function () {
            var idDC = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/Rack/LoadZoneByDataCenter", { id: idDC },
            function (MedicineData) {
                var select = $("#Rack_ZoneID");
                select.empty();
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: null
                }));
                $.each(MedicineData, function (index, itemData) {

                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: itemData.Value,
                        text: itemData.Text
                    }));
                });
            });
        });
```

Which calls the following action method:-

```
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Rack")]
public JsonResult LoadZoneByDataCenter(string id)
{
    var zonelist = repository.getrealtedzone(Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToList();

    var ZoneData = zonelist.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = m.Name,
        Value = m.ZoneID.ToString(),

    });

    return Json(ZoneData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

the above was working well , but after i have publish my application to iis the above stop working and no json data will populate the drop down . can anyone advice what is causing this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you check your network console to see if the request went through at all?

Comment: can you explain your point in detials ?

Comment: What i meant is use the network console in your browser, ex: chrome (do f12) it will show your request. You can inspect it to see what status code it returned and what response you got or whether it went to the server at all etc..

Comment: if i write the URL directly into the browser utel i will get the JSON..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this  `$.getJSON("/Rack/LoadZoneByDataCenter", { id: idDC },` one should do

```
 $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Rack/LoadZoneByDataCenter")", { id: idDC },
```

to resolve the URL

Answer (score 1):

My hunch would be this is where your issue is:

```
$.getJSON("/Rack/LoadZoneByDataCenter", { id: idDC },
```

specifically

```
"/Rack/LoadZoneByDataCenter"
```

A lot of times when you publish to something other than your local development version, the relative URIs change.

Comment: so what i should write instead ?

Comment: What is the direct URL when you test it locally?
What is the direct URL once you publish it?

Comment: If your script is in your view, see RollerCosta's answer. If not, you can try '$.getJSON("/TestApp/Rack/LoadZoneByDataCenter", { id: idDC },' or even the FQDN "$.getJSON("http://localhost/TestApp/Rack/LoadZoneByDataCenter", { id: idDC },"