# Javascript only working locally, called function returns 404 error from server after publish

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I've made some cascading dropdown lists and after at least a week with them I got them to work. So I published the project and tested it but then it didn't work. The second list never populates.

Firebug's console tells me "/Companies/GetBolag 404 Not Found" but not when I test it locally. Then it works just fine. I've tried adding `[HttpPost]` and `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]` before my JsonResult but to no avail. What am I missing?

Javascript in view:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bolag").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Kund").change(function () {
            if ($("#Kund").val() != "") {
                var options = {};
                options.url = "/Companies/GetBolag";
                alert("01");
                options.type = "POST";
                options.data = JSON.stringify({ country: $("#Kund").val() });
                options.dataType = "json";
                options.contentType = "application/json";
                alert($("#Kund").val());
                options.success = function (bolag) {
                    $("#bolag").empty();
                    alert("03");
                    for (var i = 0; i < bolag.length; i++) {
                        $("#bolag").append("<option>" + bolag[i] + "</option>");
                    }
                    $("#bolag").prop("disabled", false);
                }; 
                options.error = function () { alert("Fel vid bolagshämtning!"); };
                $.ajax(options);
            }
            else {
                $("#bolag").empty();
                $("#bolag").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

JsonResult function in controller:

```
public JsonResult GetBolag(string country)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = @"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=GRAHAM;Database=CompaniesDB;User Id=****;Password=****";
                string query = @"SELECT DISTINCT Underkund FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Småbolag] WHERE Huvudkund = '" + country + "'";
                object[] temp = new object[1];
                List<string> bolag = new List<string>();

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
                    OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                    bolag.Add("");

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        dr.GetValues(temp);
                        bolag.Add(Convert.ToString(temp[0]));
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Dispose();
                }

                return Json(bolag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var path = @"C:\log.txt";

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    using (var sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(path))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                return Json(null);
            }
        }
```

The random alert()s in the javascript is just to check where the error lies. When published `alert("01")`, `alert($("#Kund").val())` and `alert("Fel vid bolagshämtning!")` fires.

I'm sure there is a lot of bad practice in this code, but I got my position as a developer at my work without any prior experience, it's been trial-and-error, learn-by-doing as I've been handed projects and such. I mainly just need to get things to work. I know that that isn't really the way to  go about this, but please help me out!

Comment: Try get the actual link accessible without js. Could it be so easy that when deployed, you have another path and the js-link is not valid anymore? That is, the actual link is /prefix/Company/GetBolag/?

Comment: are you sure /Companies/GetBolag page exist?

NOT QUESTION RELATED:
your SQL is BAD, as you are not sanitazing your input. Use prepared statement.
What if i hack the page so you get a country of " '; drop tables; "? you can say goodbyte to your db, if you put online a code like that.

Comment: When I run it locally it all works fine. But there isn't a Companies/GetBolag page, it's a function in the controller, but as I said, it all works fine locally.
Regarding the SQL: I know I'm vulnerable to SQL injections, but the app/page is for use within our company only, there is no access to it outside the company. Also the "country" is selected in a dropdown list, there is no place to insert "; drop tables;" I believe. Anyhoo, the users can't tell the screen from the actual computer so I don't think injections will be an issue :)

Comment: I understand there isnt a page. But you should be able to reach it by typing the url in the browser anyway? If you check in firebug, is the URL for the page the following: yourserver/MySite/* and the js-url: yourserver/Company/GetBolag? My guess it is, it should be yourserver/MySite/Company/GetBolag.

Comment: It looks as though it is server/Companies/GetBolag. Works locally, but not after publishing, and it looks the same in firebug for both. With the exception of localhost instead of server.

Comment: try ResolveUrl("~/") .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days of googleing, reading and testing i found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552570/calling-an-action-method-that-return-json-is-not-woking-when-i-publish-my-web-ap).

I changed the line:

```
options.url = "/Companies/GetBolag";
```

to:

```
options.url = ("@Url.Content("~/Companies/GetBolag")");
```

And now my cascading drop downs work both locally and on the server.
I guess that this is what was suggested in the comments but I just didn't understand it.

Comment: thanks mate, i also facing the same problem and try fix it for few days until i found this. I also don't understand why!